# request for member ‘c_str’ in ‘str’, which is of non-class

Tags: c++, sdl

```
main.cpp:561:80: error: request for member ‘c_str’ in ‘str’, which is of non-class type ‘std::string [10] {aka std::basic_string<char> [10]}’
   displayFont.showHighscore[i] = TTF_RenderText_Solid(displayFont.menuFont,str.c_str(), displayFont.colorText);
```

Hi all!

According this function, this shows a ranking with data that is retrived from a member class. Also this used ttf content from another class (displayFont). When I compile this, said an error. I leave the code:

```
void showHighscore() {

    displayFont.menuFont = TTF_OpenFont("fonts/Lanehum.ttf",25);
    displayFont.colorText = { 255, 255, 255 }; // Add content

    stringstream texting[10]; // Variables
    string str[10];
    SDL_Rect posHighscore[10];

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        texting[i] << i << "#    - " << dat.topScore[i];
        str[i] = texting[i].str();
        displayFont.showHighscore[i] = TTF_RenderText_Solid(displayFont.menuFont,str.c_str(), displayFont.colorText); // OUTPUTTING ERROR :/
        posHighscore[i].x = 50; 
        posHighscore[i].y = 50 * (i+1);
    }

    while (true) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10 ; i++) {
            SDL_BlitSurface(displayFont.showHighscore[i],NULL,screen,&posHighscore[i]);     
        } // Show the rendered text

        SDL_Flip(screen);
        SDL_Delay(5000);
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: The answer is so obvious that I just can't throw it. Just have a look at how you use `str` and `texting` the line just above... (Edit: the answer was thrown anyway...)

Comment: try `str[i].c_str()`?

Answer (score 3):

`str` is an array of `string`:

```
 string str[10];
```

so you can't call `str.c_str()`. You need to call it on one of the elements of `str`, i.g. with an index:

```
str[i].c_str()
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need arrays at all:

```
stringstream texting;
texting << i << "#    - " << dat.topScore[i];
displayFont.showHighscore[i] = TTF_RenderText_Solid(displayFont.menuFont,
                                                    texting.str().c_str(),
                                                    displayFont.colorText);
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can also try by `string opt(str);`It will actually store the value of `str` in`opt` and you can call it by `opt.c_str()`

Comment: You are initialising a string with an array of strings. Class std::string does not have such a constructor. Why do you believe the answer from greatwolf (see comment below) is not the correct one?